# Compile dust template with line breaks

Tags: dust.js, dustc

Compiling a such template with `dustc`:

```
$ cat <<EOF | ./node_modules/.bin/dustc -
<p>Hi there!</p>
<p>I'm a {! dust !} template.</p>
EOF
```

outputs:

```
(function(){dust.register("-",body_0);function body_0(chk,ctx){return chk.write("<p>Hi there!</p><p>I'm a  template.</p>");}return body_0;})();
```

but **without `\n` between lines**, eg: `"<p>Hi there!</p>\n<p>I'm a  template.</p>"`

Is there any way to change this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{~n}` to create line breaks in your Dust templates. It's is especially useful within `<pre>` tags.

Comment: That's a good tip! But is there any option to automatically do this for each end of line?

Comment: Unfortunately, not as it stands. Dust strips newlines at compile time. I believe there has been some talk about changing this behavior, so you may see this fixed in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable whitespace compression with

```
dust.optimizers.format = function(ctx, node) { return node };
```

Precompiling with [gulp-dust](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-dust), there's a `preserveWhitespace` option that does just that:

```
var compile=require('gulp-dust');

// ...
gulp.src('templates/**/*.dust')
    .pipe(compile({ preserveWhitespace: true }))
    // ...
```